# Show only posts with > X characters in users admin column

Tags: wordpress, function

I used to use the plugin "Admin Columns" to add extra columns to the users columns in the WordPress backend. Now this is something that the plugin can't do:

**Show only the posts that have at least 1200 characters.**

Very special but it would be great.

This is what I got by now:

```
function count_manage_users_custom_column($output = '', $column_name, $user_id) {
  global $wpdb;

  if( $column_name !== 'post_chars_count' )
  return;

  $where = get_posts_by_author_sql( 'post', true, $user_id );
  $result = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where" );

  return '<a href="' . admin_url("edit.php?post_type=post&author=$user_id") . '" 
  title="Post Type Count">' . $result . '</a>';
}
add_filter('manage_users_custom_column', 'count_manage_users_custom_column', 10, 3);

function count_manage_users_columns($columns) {
  $columns['post_chars_count'] = __( 'Articles > 1200 chars', 'textdomain' );
  return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_users_columns', 'count_manage_users_columns');
```

It shows a new column that shows the posts that the user has published. But it shows all 3 articles, I need it to show only the one article that has > 1200 characters.

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: I know you can use ```length(post_content) > 1200``` in your WHERE clause to incorporate the size of the article into the result.

But beware that if you use Gutenberg e.g. that field in the database might contain quite a lot of metadata with a possibly hard-to-predict amount of characters. If working with rough estimates is not acceptable than this solution might not be the way forward either.

Comment: Any idea how to do that? It is not gutenberg, only standard editor. Added something like this to $where: ". ' length(post_content) > 1200 '" but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly "get_posts_by_author_sql" outputs, so you might be able to append `AND length(post_content) > 1200` to the current $where clause.

This should definitely work though:

```php
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_author=%d AND post_type=%s AND length(post_content)>%d";
$result = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($sql, $user_id, 'post', 1200));
```

Comment: This works, any idea how to strip the tags off of "post_content"?

Comment: No, not inside the sql query, I'm afraid.